# CSS3 Keyframes Animation to cycle through banner images

Tags: css

I'm trying to cycle through the six images for a banner. I have them all stacked on top of each other. I want the ones underneath to periodically take the place in front. My thoughts were to create keyframe animations for each image with the same duration that would make them appear at different percentages of time. That didn't work how I expected it to. I've tried various other things, but nothing has worked. Can anyone help?

```
<div id="splash"><a href="#"><img src="bannerimages/Banner-A.jpg" width="877" height="170" alt=""/></a>

<style>
    @-webkit-keyframes bannermove1 {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20%, 100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bannermove2 {
    20% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    0%, 40%, 100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
</style>

<img src="bannerimages/e1.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 145px; left: 217px; opacity: 0; -webkit-animation-name: bannermove1; 
-webkit-animation-duration: 30s; -webkit-animation-delay: 6s" width="877" height="170" alt=""/> 
<img src="bannerimages/Banner-C.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 145px; left: 217px; opacity: 0; -webkit-animation-name: bannermove2; -webkit-animation-duration: 30s; -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;" width="877" height="170" alt=""/>
<img src="bannerimages/Banner-B.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 145px; left: 217px; opacity: 0;" width="877" height="170" alt=""/> 
<img src="bannerimages/f1.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 145px; left: 217px; opacity: 0;" width="877" height="170" alt=""/> 
<img src="bannerimages/Banner-D.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 145px; left: 217px; opacity: 0;" width="877" height="170" alt=""/> 
</div>
```